# Run ASP.NET application in Windows Azure AND on a local server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I try to create an application that is able to run in Windows Azure cloud but also on a local server.

Most parts of the application already works on both without problem. But there are some features that I don't know how to make them run on both, for example:

Users are able to upload attachments. In Azure the files are stored in the Windows Azure Storage, on the local server they should be stored in a local folder.

I have no idea how to manage this.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is a way to have two web.config (one for Azure mode and one for local mode) so I don't have to edit the config file when I create a package for Azure or for IIS.

Comment: You can do so using MSBuild tasks, or custom ones that you can develop for that. That's, in post-build, you can define a custom target and run it so precompiled web will have the appropiate web.config. If you need further info, comment out here and I'll update my question (I know you accepted it, but I can enhance it for you ;)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you to learn about inversion of control, because you'll be able to switch file storage and other things depending on selected hosting platform.

For example, you'd have an interface called `IFileStorage` having such methods (and more):

- Create
- Append
- Remove
- ...

And two implementations for `IFileStorage`:

- WinAzureFileStorage
- DefaultFileStorage

At the end of the day, you'll be doing that:

```
IFileStorage storage = DependencyManager.Resolve<IFileStorage>();
storage.Create("SomeFile.txt");
storage.Append("SomeFile.txt", "Hello world");
```

And some inversion of control configuration will map the appropiate `IFileStorage` implementation depending on hosting platform.

If you want to learn more about **inversion of control**:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Finally, if you think this is the right way, check Castle Windsor, which is a great, solid and stable inversion of control (and other things) framework on top of .NET:

- http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. But I'm wondering how to figure out if the application runs on Azure or not.

Comment: You don't need to figure out: Azure deployment has configured the IFileStorage implementation that can work with Azure Storage, and so on. It's just a configuration thing.

Comment: +1 I have used this exact approach on a project and it worked perfectly (except it used MEF)